Why should electricity network capacity costs according to long run marginal cost pricing be paid by peak consumers only?
Electricity is distributed in a network with a max capacity $K$. Let $Y_i(t)$ be demand of person $i$ at time $t$. Then at no time $t \in [0,T]$ can $\sum_i Y_i(t) > K$ or networks breaks down.
Obviously, investing in capacity higher than $Y^*:=\max_t \{\sum_i Y_i(t)\}$ would be uneconomical so $K$ is set equal to the $Y^*$. Then obviously any unit of electricity used at any time where $\sum_i Y_i(t) < K$ would require no extra net capacity costs. So marginal costs are 0 any time $t$ where $\sum_i Y_i(t) < K$ and else equal to whatever the marginal unit of capacity costs. According to the marginal cost principle only the users of electricity at times $t$ where $\sum_i Y_i(t) = K$ should pay. This is a basic principle of peak pricing.
This reasoning is fairly straightforward. However, I suppose that there is economic literature investigating and analyzing this problem of peak pricing in more depth, maybe some lecture slides or a good textbook.
So, in short, my question is:
Can anyone refer me to good resources on the question: Why should electricity network capacity costs according to long-run marginal cost pricing be paid by peak consumers only?

Your notation seems to imply that a person's demand for electricity at time $t$ depends only on the time and not on the price they are charged.  Is that your intention?

@AdamBailey it is unintentional. I guess you could read $Y_i(t):= H_i(t,p(t))$ so demand at time $t$ depends on price but price itself being a function of time - many electricity consumers today pay prices that are different across the hours of the day - of course, some don't.

The basic peak load pricing problem is formulated in
Boiteux, M. (1949). “De la tarification des pointes de demande.” In: Revue générale
de l’électricité, pp. 321–340.
and
Steiner, P. O. (1957). “Peak loads and efficient pricing.” In: The Quarterly Journal of Economics, pp. 585–610.
The most simple set up considers $T=2$ periods. The important assumption is that storage is impossible hence demand must balance supply in each period. Furthermore, the same capital $K$ is used in both periods and production $q_1$ and $q_2$ must both be weekly smaller than the capacity/capital $K$.
With inverse demand given as $P_1(q_1)$ and $P_2(q_2)$ and the cost as
\begin{align}
C(q_1,q_2,K) = b(q_1+q_2) + rK,
\end{align}
the welfare optimization problem can be formulated as
\begin{align}
\max_{q_1,q_2,K} &\ \int_{0}^{q_1} P_1(z) dz + \int_{0}^{q_2} P_2(z) dz - C(q_1,q_2,K)\\[8pt]
s.t. &\ \ \ q_1 \leq K \ \wedge \ q_2 \leq K
\end{align}
For which the first order conditions of the Lagrangian is given as
\begin{align}
P_1(q_1) - b - \lambda_1 = 0\\[8pt]
P_2(q_2) - b - \lambda_2 = 0\\[8pt]
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 - r = 0.
\end{align}
When the cost of capital $r>0$ it follows that $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2>0$ so at least one of the shadow prices is strictly above 0 implying that
\begin{align}
q_1 = K \ \ \vee  \ \ q_2 = K,
\end{align}
such that there will never be invested in capacity that is not used.
Furthermore, in this case
\begin{align}
P_{1}(K) - b + P_2(K) - b = r,
\end{align}
states that the sum of prices net variable cost $b$ equals the unit cost of capital. So if demand is peaking in both periods then prices in both periods are above short-run marginal cost $b$.
In case one shadow price is $0$ - assume $\lambda_2 = 0$ - because the demand is so low that production is less than capacity $q_2<K$ then
\begin{align}
P_{1}(K) &= b+r \\[8pt]
P_2(q_2) &= b,
\end{align}
such that only the peak period $t=1$ where production is at capacity $q_1=K$ is priced for the capital cost $r$.
Peak pricing is commonly used in transportation, pricing for hotel rooms, plane tickets as well as network service. The essential component is time-varying demand combined with the impossibility of storage.
